# How do I use ContentMD5 Properly in Step Function Definition when using PutObject on an ObjectLock Enabled S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, md5, aws-step-functions

Currently, I have written a Step Function definition that uses PutObject SDK to an S3 bucket that has ObjectLock Enabled. Because of Object Lock enabled on my S3, I need to pass ContentMD5 from the Definition. This is the definition I am currently using:

```
{
    "Comment": "PutObject to S3",
    "StartAt": "PutObject",
    "States": {
      
        "PutObject": {
          
            "Type": "Task",
            "End": true,
            "Parameters": {
                "Body": "test data",
                "Bucket": "worm-bucket-test",
                "Key": "logs.txt",
"ContentMD5": "States.Base64Encode(States.Hash('test data', 'MD5'))"                },
            "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:putObject",
                      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::aws-sdk:s3:putObject",
                "Catch": [ {
  "ErrorEquals": [ "States.TaskFailed" ],
  "Next": "Wait1Sec"
} ]
        
        },
      "Wait1Sec": {
  "Type": "Wait",
  "Seconds": 1,
  "Next": "PutObject"
}
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I continue to receive the following error:

{
"Error": "S3.S3Exception",
"Cause": "The Content-MD5 you specified was invalid. (Service: S3, Status Code: 400, Request ID: xxx, Extended Request ID: xxx)"
}

I am able to create a Lambda, and write code that handles Content-MD5 data to S3, but my goal is to have this same functionality from SF to S3 directly without having to use a Lambda function. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Try `"ContentMD5": "States.Hash('test data', 'MD5')"`

Comment: @jellycsc Thank you for your response. I have attempted this already, then attempted it again upon your suggestion. It still failed with the same error of being invalid.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a ".$" try: "ContentMD5.$": "States.Base64Encode(States.Hash('test data', 'MD5'))"